# Investigate a string in java whether it is include some special signs?

Tags: java

I have the following java mehod and have some conditions for the parameter searchPattern:

```
public boolean checkPatternMatching(String sourceToScan, String searchPattern) {

    boolean patternFounded;

    if (sourceToScan == null) {
        patternFounded = false;
    } else {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(searchPattern),
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceToScan);
        patternFounded = matcher.find();
    }
    return patternFounded;
}
```

I want to search for all letter (uppercase and lowercase must be considered) and only (!) the special signs "-", ":" and "=". All other values must be occured a "false" from this method.

How can i implemented this logic for the parameter "searchPattern"?

Comment: Try this `"[[a-zA-Z]!-,=\\s]+"`

Comment: And how it must be implemented if only letter (in uppercase and lowercase) are important? Why you asked as comment?

Comment: If only letter `"[[a-zA-z]\\s]+"`. `\\s` is for spaces. I wasn't sure if my answer was right for your situation. So I just posted a comment. If it works, I'll change it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `searchPattern = "[a-zA-Z:=-]"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `[a-zA-Z=,_!:]`

```
String pattern ="[a-zA-Z=,_!:]";        
String input="hello_:,!=";
if(input.matches(pattern)){
       System.out.println("true");
}else{
       System.out.println("false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"[[a-zA-Z]!-=:\\s]+"
```

The square bracket mean a character class in which each character in which it will match all character within the brackets. The `+` means one or more characters in the character class, and the `\\s` is for spaces.

So if you want just letter an spaces, as per your comment in the original post

```
"[[a-zA-z]\\s]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
searchPattern = "^[A-Za-z!=:-]+$"
```

`^` means "begins with"
`$` means "ends with"
`[A-Za-z!=:-]` is a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) that contains any letter or the symbols `!`, `=`, `:`, `-`
`+` means "1 or more` of the preceding

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This will work if the string will **solely** contain those symbols, ie **no** spaces or anything else.

If you want a string that contains the given symbols **and** may also contain whitespace, use:

```
searchPattern = "^[A-Za-z!=:-\\s]+$"
```

`\\s` stands for white-space character

Finally, if you want to simply see if a string contains any one of these symbols, you can use:

```
searchPattern = "[A-Za-z!=:-]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `searchPattern` as `([a-zA-Z]!-:=)+`

[image]

Comment: This works only if OP wants at least one of the characters to be included in the string.  This does not restrict the string to be only of these characters (OP did not specify if this is the case, but you give the answer with no explanation as to what it does).  Also, why are you using a capturing group?