# Check special arrangement of specific signs in a string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to check a string whether it includes a specific arrangements of letters and numbers.

**Valid** arrangements are for example:

```
X
X-Y
A-H-K-L-J-Y
A-H-J-Y

123
12?
12*
12-17
```

**Invalid** are for example:

```
-X-Y
-XY

*12
?12
```

I have written this method in java to solve this problem (but i don´t have some experiences with regular expressions):

```
public boolean checkPatternMatching(String sourceToScan, String searchPattern) {

    boolean patternFounded;

    if (sourceToScan == null) {
       patternFounded = false;
    } else {
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(searchPattern),
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceToScan);
       patternFounded = matcher.find();
    }
    return patternFounded;
}
```

How can i implemented this requirement with regular expressions?

By the way: It is a good solution to check a string, whether it includes numeric content by using the method isNumeric from the java class StringUtils?

//EDIT

The link, which was edited by the admins includes not specific arrangements of characters but only an appearance of characters with regular expressions in general !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a good while trying to help, answering to constantly changing questions, just found out that [the same was asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627034/investigate-a-string-in-java-whether-it-is-include-some-special-signs), and that the OP [doesn't accept answers to his questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504767/marwief?tab=questions)...all I have left to say is *good night sir, good luck*

**n-th answer follows:**

First pattern: `[a-z](-[a-z])*` : a letter, possibly followed by more letters, separated by `-`.

Second pattern: `\d+(-\d+)*[?*]*` : a number, possibly followed by more numbers, separated by `-`, and possibly ending with `?` or `*`.

So join them together: `^([a-z](-[a-z])*)|(\d+(-\d+)*[?*]*)$`. `^` and `$` mark the beginning and the end of the string.

Few more comments on the code: you don't need to use `Pattern.quote`, and you should use `matches()` instead of `find()`, because `find()` returns `true` if *any* part of the string matches the pattern, and you want *the whole* string:

```
public static boolean checkPatternMatching(String sourceToScan, String searchPattern) {
    boolean patternFounded;

    if (sourceToScan == null) {
       patternFounded = false;
    } else {
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceToScan);
       patternFounded = matcher.matches();
    }
    return patternFounded;
}
```

Called like this: `checkPatternMatching(s, "^([a-z](-[a-z])*)|(\\d+(-\\d+)*[?*]*)$")`

About the second question, this is the [current implementation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java?view=markup) of `StringUtils.isNumeric`:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(final CharSequence cs) {
    if (isEmpty(cs)) {
        return false;
    }
    final int sz = cs.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(cs.charAt(i)) == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So no, there is nothing wrong about it, that is as simple as it gets. But you need to include an external JAR in your program, which I find unnecessary if you just want to use such a simple method.

Comment: Thanks! Is this pattern correct for the expression "X-Y": [a-z](\-[a-z])

Comment: @Marwief yes, for that simple case you can even remove the parentheses. They are used above to allow repetition of `-[a-z]`

Comment: What do you think about my another question?: By the way: It is a good solution to check a string, whether it includes numeric content by using the method isNumeric from the java class StringUtils?

Comment: I have a question again: How must be implemented the regular expression pattern, if arrangements like this must be possible: "*12" or "1?2" or "12*456"?

Comment: @Marwief can the `*` and `?` be at the beginning of the number? just at the end? anywhere? Note that `*12` is said to be invalid in your question

Comment: sorry that was my mistake! The * and ? can be anywhere for example: "*12" or "1?2" or "12*456"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should first remove the `Pattern.quote()` method because that would turn the inputting patterns into string literals; and those are not really useful in your context.

To match the valid arrangements with letters, something like this should work:

```
^[a-z](?:-[a-z])*$
```

For the numbers (if I understood the rules correctly):

```
^\\d+(?:[?*]|-\\d+)*$
```

And if you want to combine them:

```
^(?:[a-z](?:-[a-z])*|\\d+(?:[?*]|-\\d+)*)$
```

I'm not familiar with Java itself, nor the `isNumeric` method, sorry.

---

As per your comment, if you want to accept `*12` or `1?2` or `12*456`, you can use:

```
^\\*?\\d+(?:[?*]\\d*|-\\d+)*$
```

Then add it to the previous regex like so:

```
^(?:[a-z](?:-[a-z])*|\\*?\\d+(?:[?*]\\d*|-\\d+)*)$
```

Comment: @Marwief Is `??12` valid? Is `1*?2` valid? Is `*12?3` valid?